# Azure File Storage (SMB) expected max performance

Tags: azure-storage

According to the published documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-scalability-targets

The max 8K IOPS for File Storage is 1,000 per share, which limits effectively as 8.192 MB/s, but it later says that the throughput per share is up to 60 MB/s.

Without a disk sector size, I assume it uses 8K chunks, else why did they choose that number.

So the lower number is the real throughput? Then why publish 60 MB/s ? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can get target throughput by using larger IO.

1000 IOps is the hard limit.  That means you can attain 4MB/sec for 4k IOs, 8MB/sec for 8k IOs, and 32MB/sec for 32k IOs and so on.

In case of Throughput -  60 MB/s, is a "target", but not a hard limit neither a guarantee. However its a number good to know in order to plan your workload.

So for example if you do 1MB IOs, the per share throttle wouldn’t kick in until you hit 1000 MB/s – which you won’t be able to do.  So in that case you only need to think about the targets.

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm confused because I have no control over the size of the IO, since its SMB to a UNC path. Or am I wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused because I have no control over the size of the IO, since its SMB to a UNC path. Or am I wrong? Thanks

In my opinion, the IOPS is the number of times to accept I / O instructions per second. Refers to the system in the unit time to deal with the maximum I/O.

It means the file storage could deal with 1000(8KB) in or out instructions per second.

Normally, we will not access the one second deal with 1000(8KB) I/O instructions.

So we will just consider the throughput(60MB/s) in the one I/O instruction.

I think we could control the size of the IO even if its SMB to a UNC path.

Answer (score 0):

You can now increase the IOPS for an Azure file share from 1000 to up to 10,000

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-how-to-create-large-file-share

You can also use Azure premium files for up to 100,000 IOPS